# Output from an Excel Listbox (multiselect) as a column or Range

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, checkedlistbox

I have a summary report refers to raw data for multiple countries on another sheet. The user can choose which Country's data to show by using a simple validated cell dropdown.

[image: generic country dropdown singleselect]

However this is single select, and I wish to make this list multiselect. It seems that I should use a Listbox (ActiveX) to do this. I have created a Listbox with the range of Countries, however I can't find how to use the countries which are selected.

[image: multiselect listbox]

I'd like to output the selected Countries into a column in a sheet, or directly into a Range to be referred to by formula. Is this possible, or is there a better method?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this (here with `Listbox.Change` event):

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

    With ListBox1

        Dim i As Byte
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            Debug.Print .Selected(i)
        Next i

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for being utterly dim, but where is this output "printed" to and how do I use it in a formula? My familiarity with VBA is very small.

Comment: it returns `true` or `false` in Immediate window in vba editor. How to use it in cells? instead of `Debug.Print` use `Cells(i +1, "A") = .selected(i)` to get results from A1 down direction.

Comment: Okay, I think that gives me something to work with. It's quite indirect but I can probably figure out how to get a list/range of Countries.